# Mix two PFQuery results

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery

I want to have an mix of two `PFQuery` results. In my code below, I'm getting the results of the intersection of the two results (so all users who's username AND fullName contain `self.searchText`), I want to to include all the results (so all users who's username equals `self.searchText` and all users who's fullName equals `self.searchText`).

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"username" containsString:self.searchText];
[query whereKey:@"fullName" containsString:self.searchText];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    } else {
        self.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
        NSLog(@"%@", objects);
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}];
```

Comment: your code seems fine, what issue do you get ?

Comment: do two queries separately and move the objects to a same mutable array. reload tableView afterwards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are trying to do is get the Union (OR) of the two sets not their intersection (AND)

use the following code should bring you all users that match either of those criterias

```
PFQuery *firstQuery = [PFUser query];
[firstQuery whereKey:@"username" containsString:self.searchText];

PFQuery *secondQuery = [PFUser query];
[secondQuery whereKey:@"fullName" containsString:self.searchText];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:@[firstQuery ,secondQuery ]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
  if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
} else {
    self.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
    NSLog(@"%@", objects);
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
}];
```

and here is the link to the guide

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#queries-compound/iOS

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> so all users who's username equals self.searchText and all users who's fullName equals self.searchText

what you really mean is `OR`, instead of `AND` (because `AND` is what your current code does).

To create an `OR` relationship you will need to create 2 different queries and then use `orQueryWithSubqueries:` to combine them.